# FindRoot with lists as input

Tags: list-manipulation, equation-solving, finance

I have to calculate different Internal Rates of Returns by using the `FindRoot` function.

```
cashflowlist={-10,3,12}  
FindRoot[TimeValue[Cashflow@cashflowlist, r, 0] == 0, {r, .05}]
```

However, this needs to work for many more potential cashflows. E.g.

```
cashflowlistlong={{-10,3,12},{-9,4,12},{-8,2,11}}
```

When inserting the `cashflowlistong` in the function defined above, it does not work at all.

```
FindRoot[TimeValue[Cashflow/@cashflowlistlong, r, 0] == 0, {r, .05}]
```

My goal is to get a list which contains only the three return rates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make the whole solving step a function and map it over `cashflowlistlong`:

```
sol = FindRoot[TimeValue[Cashflow[#], r, 0] == 0, {r, .05}] & /@ cashflowlistlong
```

> {{r -> 0.255667}, {r -> 0.398112}, {r -> 0.304248}}

You obtain the list of numerical solutions simply by `ReplaceAll`:

```
r /. sol
```

> {0.255667, 0.398112, 0.304248}

**Edit**

Actually, for list with three elements, your equations boil down to quadratic equations in one variable, so also `Solve` can compute the solutions symbolically:

```
Solve[TimeValue[Cashflow@Array[a, 3], r, 0] == 0, r]
```

> {
>
> {r -> (-2*a[1] - a[2] - Sqrt[a[2]^2 - 4*a[1]*a[3]])/(2*a[1])},
>
> {r -> (-2*a[1] - a[2] + Sqrt[a[2]^2 - 4*a[1]*a[3]])/(2*a[1])}
>
> }

Comment: Dear Henrik, Thank you very much. Do you know also know how to only extract the numerical values? As far as I understand it, we've got three associations now but they all have "r" as a key which is a bit confusing for me.

Comment: Silvan, you're welcome.

Comment: Have a nice evening and again, thanks for your help :)

Comment: Nice evening also to you!